# Premature EOF In apache spark at cache statement

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark scala code which works on json data.
After running for an hour , It shows premature EOF error. I have searched and found some solutions but none of them is working.

Stacktrace shows something related to datastreamer.

Error is something like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov44r.png).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please add more details about the error?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: What version of HDFS are you using?

Comment: do u mean hadoop?

Comment: yes, Hadoop version.